# Need to subtract and remove leading zeros

Tags: python, decimal, subtraction

In the following program, I need to subtract the bartype from the variable "b" and then in one section of code remove leading zeros from  2.5

I have tried moving the subtraction around in different places of the code

```
b=int(input('Please enter weight to load on the bar:'))
bartype=int(input('Please enter bar weight'))
x = bartype
b = (b-x)
print(b//45, "45's")
b = b%45
print(b//25, "25's")
b = b%25
print(b//10, "10's")
b = b%10
# I need to print 2.5 without leading zeros
print(b/2.5, "2.5's")
b = b%2.5

print(b//5, "5's")
b = b%5
```

So here is an example 365 = 365 - bartype  and then weight types ( 45, 25, etc) should be broken down. The answer should be 6 45's  2 25's. example 320 should equal 6 45's and 2 2.5's

Comment: `print(int(b/2.5), "2.5's")`?

Answer (score 0):

```
b = int(input('Please enter weight to load on the bar :  '))-int(input('Please enter bar weight :  '))
print(int(b//45), "45's") # int() to convert float value to int
b = b%45
print(int(b//25), "25's")
b = b%25
print(int(b//10), "10's")
b = b%10
# I need to print 2.5 without leading zeros
print(int(b/2.5), "2.5's")
b = b%2.5
print(int(b//5), "5's")
b = b%5
```

Comment: Thanks, I also need to  subtract  (b-bartype)

Comment: I also need to force print(int(b//45), "45's") to be an even number

Comment: ok `b = (b-x)` i understand you are doing this. Here you have `b = int(input('Please enter weight to load on the bar:'))` and `bartype = int(input('Please enter bar weight'))` and then you are storing `bartype` to `x`  if you see the above code in first line `b = int(input('Please enter weight to load on the bar :  '))-int(input('Please enter bar weight :  '))`, you will find out that the first line is similar to 'b-bartype', and for the even value of `print(int(b//45), "45's")` you can do `print(int(b//45), "45's") if int(b//45)%2 == 0 else print(int(b//45)+1, "45's");`

Comment: Thanks, it's getting closer

Comment: b = int(input('Please enter weight to load on the bar: '))-int(input('Please enter bar weight : '))

print(int(b//45), "45's") if int(b//45)%2 == 0 else print(int(b//45)-1, "45's");

b = b%45
l.


print(b//25, "25's")
#print(int(b//25), "25's") if int(b//25)%2 == 0 else print(int(b//25), "25's");
b = b%25

print(b//10, "10's")
# print(int(b//10), "10's")
b = b%10

print(b//5, "5's")
# print(int(b//5), "5's")
b = b%5

print(int(b/2.5), "2.5's")
b = b%2.5

# Currently working on a bug where the program works with  405 but fails with 365

Comment: what input are you providing

Comment: I am putting in 365 for the weight and 45 for the bar. So the program should display 6 = 45's and 2 = 25's